# Working with variables from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a database that will allow the user to see the location of a student on a given date. I am relatively new to PHP/MySQL and struggling to come up with the SELECT and code to display the following table:

```
location
+----------+----------+---------+-----+
| date (1) | date (2) | date(3) | ... |
+----------+----------+---------+-----+
| student  | student  | student | ... |
| student  |          | student |     |
|          |          | student |     |
+----------+----------+---------+-----+
```

The table needs to show for every individual location. All defined dates in the header must always show, even if there are no students at that location for that date.

The date header is dynamic (user definable) and taken from a table called 'dates' referencing a column entitled 'date'.

The student data is taken from a table called 'students' which holds a range of different information about each student, including the columns 'firstname' & 'lastname'.

There are a number of different holiday locations in the table 'locations'.

Users tell the database the locations of students by updating a 4th table entitled 'destinations' which is structured with the column headers:

```
ID | date_ID | student_ID | location_ID
```

My apologies if this is a somewhat garbled question. Please feel free to ask for clarification as I appreciate that I lack the knowledge to be more precise.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the dates fixed (it seems like it given that you have a date_ID field)? Cross join the table of dates to the table of locations and left join the student location to it.

Comment: The dates are fixed but user defined (via a settings page) Surely it can't be done with one select statement? There are variable results for each date...

Comment: It can be done in one statement, depending on the exact format. For example if you cross join the locations with the dates you get every possible combination of those that you are interested in. LEFT JOIN the destinations table gets you all the students for each date / location. You can then use GROUP_CONCAT to put together all the students for that date / location into one field. If you could put up the table declares and a little sample data (sql fiddle might be easiest for this) I can try and give you more details.

Comment: That's brilliant @Kickstart thank you! I've managed to work it out with those guidelines. :)